# How to avoid sql injection?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I have this code

```
$where = '';
if (isset($_POST['lvl']) && $vals = $_POST['lvl']) {
    $where = 'WHERE ';
$first = false;
if ($vals[0] === '0') {
    $where .= 'team = "neutral"';
    unset($vals[0]);
    $first = true;
}
if (count($vals)) {
    if ($first) $where .= ' OR ';
    $where .= 'lvl IN (\'' . implode('\',\'', $vals) . '\')';
}}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table $where";
$res = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$res->execute();
$num = $res->rowCount();
echo "<h2>".$num."</h2>";
```

It works, but if someone did something, then [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-p5xzuA0_kzY/UQKrLFx2MvI/AAAAAAAAARU/qXbO9BNKFf8/s848/SQL.jpg) happens. How to fix this?

**UPD**: added PDO code

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: no ways use prepared queries ....

Comment: Please, do not close this question. It require a bit more complex answer rather than just "use prepared statements" with basic example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PDO::quote() for all string values.
Also you should never select all the records when you need only to count them. Ask a database to do it for you

```
$where = '';
if (!empty($_POST['lvl'])) {
    $vals = $_POST['lvl'];
    $where = 'WHERE ';
    if ($vals[0] === '0') {
        $where .= "team = 'neutral'";
        unset($vals[0]);
        if ($vals) {
            $where .= " OR ";
        }
    }
    if ($vals) {
        foreach ($vals as $i => $val) {
           $vals[$i] = $DBH->quote($val);
        }
        $where .= "lvl IN (".implode(',', $vals).")";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM $table $where";
$res = $DBH->query($sql);
$res->execute();
$row = $res->fetch();
echo "<h2>".$row['num']."</h2>";
```

By the way, with my own class the code would be slightly less complex, because it makes manual escaping unnecessary (it is using mysqli, not PDO though).

```
$where = '';
if (!empty($_POST['lvl'])) {
    $vals = $_POST['lvl'];
    $where = 'WHERE ';
    if ($vals[0] === '0') {
        $where .= "team = 'neutral'";
        unset($vals[0]);
        if ($vals) {
            $where .= " OR ";
        }
    }
    if ($vals) {
        $where .= $db->parse("lvl IN (?a)",$vals);
    }
}
$num = $db->getOne("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM ?n ?p",$table, $where);
echo "<h2>".$num."</h2>";
```

Comment: rowCount is proof that code works and do right things. Original code receives all from db and creates many html code. Anyway, thanks, first code block is that i need.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in order to escape values. Note that it is `mysqli` because `mysql` functions have been depreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this is the future, and prepared statements are now.

Comment: try this http://simon.net.nz/articles/protecting-mysql-sql-injection-attacks-using-php/

Comment: I should have been more clear and used "will be depreciated".

Comment: escaping "values" has nothing to do with injections

Answer (score -1):

Use PDO with named parameters

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: this doesn't actually answers the question